can't run npm run ios in terminal
My name is Pedro and I'm looking to start in Software Development.
I've been trying to take this path for a few years but have been unsucessful because of lack of discipline (mustly due to the time I have available). But I noticed, that it was mainly because of not having a project or idea to develop and work on.
Now I do! However, my project is a mobile application that I'm looking to develop in React Native/Expo.
I haven't developed anything else and I'm using a lot of Youtube/ChatGPT/VSC recommended documentation to know the steps I need to follow.
When creating the npx create-expo-app@latest app, I tried to run the npm run ios command but I'm getting the following error.
Unable to run simctl:
Error: xcrun simctl help exited with non-zero code: 72
? Xcode must be fully installed before you can continue. Continue to the App Store? › (Y/n)Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:207:21)
I installed XCode iOS 17.5 Simulator and expected it to run, but I'm lost in what to do next.
Appreciate the help and guidance!

sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
Try runing this in the terminal
Not sure why you encountered this problem but it looks simmilar to this one
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21727
People there said that runing this line in the terminal fixed the problem
If you will still have the problem, feel free to reach out in the comments

Sorry for my late reply, I was on Vacations in Peru.
I used your command but I'm now following this tutorial https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/set-up-your-environment/?platform=ios&device=simulated&mode=development-build
When I try to follow step 3 and run eas build:configure I get this error:
(node:52902) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
Run this command inside a project directory.
Error: build command failed.
